# How to add a click listener to an InputElement in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I've created the following checkbox

```
    import com.google.gwt.dom.client.InputElement;
    ...
    final InputElement bulkEditCheckbox = Document.get().createCheckInputElement();
```

Tried many formulas, but just can't wrap it or add a listener to it. Any suggestions?

PS: getting the following error when trying to wrap with SimpleCheckBox.wrap():

```
‘A widget that has an existing parent widget may not be added to the detach list’
```

Comment: Why do you need to create an InputElement if you then try to wrap it into a Widget?

Comment: Thank you fro replying, had tried that before, but my ClickHandler simply doesn't work when doing it that way (directly with a SimpleCheckBox)

Comment: I am glad that you figured it out, but I feel like there is a much simpler and cleaner way to accomplish that.

Comment: I totally agree, I'm being enforced to use this low level approach by some project constraints (old GWT version, old EXT GWT version and our customization framework). All this provides me a not very flexible interface... Again thanks for checking.

Comment: Just a simple question. Why do you need this. You can use checkbox widget provided by gwt. A click handler on checkbox is equvivalent to value change handler unless you have some fancy requirement

Comment: @AbhijithNagaraja That's because I'm modifying an existing Widget. It cannot be extended, so I'm actually changing it's functionality by doing this. I know it's not recommended, but redoing the widget would take me a huge refactoring in the code.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my issue:

```
DOM.sinkEvents(element, Event.ONCLICK);
DOM.setEventListener(element, new EventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
        if (Event.ONCLICK == event.getTypeInt()) {
            ...
        }
    }
});
```